# For loop Array Display

Tags: php, arrays

i have array value like this

```
Array ( 
    [0] => A1
    [1] => A2
) 
Array ( 
    [0] => B1 
    [1] => B2
    [2] => B3
)
```

For exploding

```
$explodedeductedfinal = explode(",",$CODE);
```

this is my php code for outputting the data in td

```
foreach($explodedeductedfinal as $is){
    $bankname = trim($is);

     if (!empty($bankname)) {
         echo   "<td class='center'>$bankname</td>";
     }else{
         echo   "<td class='center'>'novalue'</td>";
     }
}
```

Output:

```
|Column A|Column B|Column C| 
    A1       A2
    B1       B2      B3
```

Desired Output:

```
 |Column A|Column B|Column C| 
      A1      A2    novalue
      B1      B2      B3
```

i just want to output when the $bankname is empty it will show no value

Comment: What is the value of `$CODE` ?

Comment: the array......

Comment: The problem is your foreach never goes to column c in your first array because there's only two elements.

Comment: its from my database..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third element is not empty, it doesn't exist, so `foreach` will only loop two.  You might force it to the length you want and supply default values:

```
$default = array_fill(0, 3, 'novalue');
$explodedeductedfinal = array_replace($default, explode(",", $CODE));

foreach($explodedeductedfinal as $is){
     $bankname = trim($is);
     echo "<td class='center'>$bankname</td>";
}
```

Comment: Call to undefined function arrray_fill() i

Comment: if you ever need it for an undetermined amount of columns,
max(array_map('count', $The_array_of_arrays)); should return you the number of columns you need

Comment: i have quick question how about if the array all have no value ?

Comment: Then you will get 3 columns of `novalue`

Comment: @AbraCadaver sir how about if theres no array value?

Comment: it only give me 2 novalue

Comment: I don't know what you mean, why don't you try it.

Comment: i mean 3 empty value not array

Comment: @RalphThomasHopper how will i use that?

Comment: $maxColumns=max(array_map('count', $CODE));

$default = array_fill(0, $maxColumns, 'novalue');
$explodedeductedfinal = array_replace($default, explode(",", $CODE));

foreach($explodedeductedfinal as $is){
     $bankname = trim($is);
     echo "<td class='center'>$bankname</td>";
}

Answer (score 0):

well the foreach will go through every element of the array.

```
if (!empty($bankname)) {
```

Would not be empty since you are in a foreach. If there is always 3 columns, you could look into using a simple for statement, or alternatively, use javascript to fill in all empty cells in a table with a default value. for that, see this fiddle. I have had to use it in the past.

http://jsfiddle.net/yL8t1psf/1/

Comment: OK, and is your array 3 columns at all times?

Answer (score 0):

Calculate the maximum index of your arrays and loop on that instead of foreach.  From a database, you could get the max number of values.  Then use isset() to verify if the value is set for that index or not.

I coded this (quick and dirty, no database, no output formatting):

```
<table>
<?php
    $arA = array(0 => 'A1', 1 => 'A2');
    $arB = array(0 => 'B1', 1 => 'B2', 2 => 'B3');

    function output_ar($ar,$maxindex)
    {
        for ($i = 0; $i <= $maxindex; $i++)
        {
            if (isset($ar[$i]))
            {
                echo "<td>" . $ar[$i] . "</td>";
            }
            else
            {
                echo "<td>novalue</td>";
            }
        }
    }

    $maxindex = max(count($arA),count($arB)) -1;
    echo "<tr>\n";
    output_ar($arA,$maxindex);
    echo "</tr>\n<tr>\n";
    output_ar($arB,$maxindex);
    echo "</tr>\n";
?>
</table>
```

Comment: The code to fill your array from the database is left to you as an exercise :-) .  Your initial question does not ask for that.

Comment: how ? im newbee in terms of php sorry

Comment: PHP: https://www.w3schools.com/php/.  And for MySQL connectivity, https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp.  StackOverflow is not a school, but w3schools is!